# Knockoutjs observe nested object and subscribe for changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Having a look at knockout js and the mapping plugin.
I noticed that if I pass an object, I cannot subscribe to it for changes.
Basically, I want to be notified if any member of the object changes. I don't really care
to get back the attribute that changed (but if it is possible would like to know how)

```
function EventsKoModel(data){
    var self = this;
    self.event = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
   //the below throws Error 
    //TypeError: self.event.subscribe is not a function
    self.event.subscribe(function(){
       console.log("something changed");
     });
}

var data = {
    'id': 14124124124124,
    'name': 'Some Event',
    'events': [{
       'id': 1
     },{
        'id': 2
      }]
}
var d = new EventsKoModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(d);
```

However, if I pass an array with objects, it works
I saw that when passing an object to fromJS, the returned object does not have a subscribe method
Is there anyway to work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the subscriber to fire each time the `event` is updated including the first time it gets set.  You could try this;

```
function EventsKoModel(data){
    var self = this;
    self.event = ko.observable();
    self.event.subscribe(function(){
        console.log("something changed");
    });
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
```

Comment: The event gets fired the first time but not when I update the mapping, after getting the data from the server. I use ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self) when I get the data

Comment: OK it worked. My bad. But please explain something to me. The event gets triggered even if the event attribute does not get updated? Because, in the example above, self.event is never changed

Comment: In this case, `self.event` is an `observable` whose value is a plain object (which by coincidence happens to contain some `observables`, but this isn't important. Therefore, any change to the object itself will trigger subscriptions, and any change to the properties of an object is a change to the object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there any way to find which exactly attribute, in a nested object, has changed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirements a while back and wrote Knockout Reactor for this. It does a good job at subscribing to hierarchical models and provides most of the functionality you might need to get you going right away.

Here's the link to it:

https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor